Unit tests checking signals and services within an effect
In an ngAfterViewInit I have the following check, following the declarations:
protected iconNotificacaoNova = false;
@ViewChild('popoverNotificacao') popoverNotificacaoComponent!: NgbPopover;
@Input() public notificacoesView: boolean = false;
protected readonly notificacoesService = inject(NotificacoesService);

...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  if (this.notificacoesView) {
    effect(() => {
      if (this.popoverNotificacaoComponent?.isOpen() && this.notificacoesService.notificacoes().length) {
        this.iconNotificacaoNova = false;
      } else if (this.notificacoesService.notificacoes().length) {
        this.iconNotificacaoNova = true;
      }
      if (!this.notificacoesService.notificacoes().length) {
        this.popoverNotificacaoComponent.close();
      }
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }, { injector: this.injector });
    }
}

this.notificacoesService.notificacoes being a signal to array type.
In my test I do it as follows:
describe('NavMenuComponent NgAfterViewInit', () => {
    let component: NavMenuComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavMenuComponent>;

    let mockActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;
    let notificacoesServiceMock: jasmine.SpyObj<NotificacoesService>;
    let popoverNotificacaoComponentMock: jasmine.SpyObj<NgbPopover>;


    it("must call the instance's close method popoverNotificationComponent", async () => {
        notificacoesServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('NotificacoesService', ['notificacoes', 'updateNotificacoes']);
        popoverNotificacaoComponentMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('NgbPopover', ['isOpen', 'close']);

        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                NavMenuComponent,
                NgbPopoverModule,
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute },
                { provide: NotificacoesService, useValue: notificacoesServiceMock },
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavMenuComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        popoverNotificacaoComponentMock.isOpen.and.returnValue(true);
        popoverNotificacaoComponentMock.close.and.returnValue();
        component.popoverNotificacaoComponent = popoverNotificacaoComponentMock;

        const spyCDR = spyOn((component as any).cdr, 'detectChanges');

        component.notificacoesView = true;

        notificacoesServiceMock.notificacoes.and.returnValue([]);

        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect((component as any).iconNotificacaoNova).toBeFalse();
        expect(spyCDR).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(popoverNotificacaoComponentMock.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});

Result:

Expected spy NgbPopover.close to have been called
I hope to get to this part of the code:
if (!this.notificacoesService.notificacoes().length) {
  this.popoverNotificacaoComponent.close();
}

Code-Coverage:

I'm using Angular 16.2.12
